# Theorem for algorithmic approach to find an integral basis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

So there is [this PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ac59/767929639347bb2d0ef52621d973ad743af8.pdf) by John Paul Cook with the following theorem:
[image]
Following it is a 9-step algorithm to find an integral basis. The last step is:
[image]
So for the case when $\Delta[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n]$ is not squarefree, but all elements of the form $(**)$ are not integral, algorithm suggests that we have found our integral basis, but the Theorem 3.4 suggests that there has to be another integral element. What am I missing? And by the way, does that theorem has some searchable name?

Comment: I think the last paragraph in your question is causing the confusion. The set of elements are integral but the discriminant is not square-free. That suggests that there may be integral elements which have smaller discriminant.

Comment: @daruma not exactly. I think you mean that there may be further integral elements, with smaller discriminant and not of the form $(**)$. My question is that, by supposition at the step 9, we can face a situation where a discriminant of these integral elements is not squarefree, but there are no integral elements of the form $(**)$, which contradicts theorem 3.4.